# building Angular application for production

Tags: angular

I see many testing modules beeing included into my final production build. Could anyone help me and tell how to avoid this?

```
 Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @ngrx/core : module as esm5
 Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @ngrx/store : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling simplebar-angular : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @ngrx/effects : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @ngrx/effects/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @ngrx/store/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @ngrx/store-devtools : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling ngx-cookie-service : es2015 as esm2015
 Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
```

Comment: Can you please explain in better way what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Which 'testing' modules?

Comment: @David for example i guess `@angular/common/testing` module is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These modules will not be included in the final build. Compilation is carried out by the Angular Compatibility Compiler (`ngcc`) for ivy, only once, for all angular modules that you installed (even if you do not use them).

When doing the actual bundling, webpack will only include code that you actually use in the final bundles. So none of the testing modules will be included in your final build (unless you referenced this modules in your app code, which should not be the case)

Comment: so the only way to evaluate what goes into the final build is to use tool like `source-map-explorer` ?

Comment: It's easier with sourcemap yes, otherwise you can still inspect the generated bundles. But you don't have to worry about this

Answer (score -2):

You can exclude these files from been building in tsconfig, like:

```
"exclude": [
  ".*.spec.ts"
]
```